# How to interpolate 3D points computed from a Kinect to get a ball trajectory?

Tags: c++, math, kinect, interpolation, least-squares

I'm getting 3D points from the Kinect via OpenNI. Let's say I have :

X = [93.7819,76.8463,208.386,322.069,437.946,669.999]
Y = [-260.147,-250.011,-230.717,-211.104,-195.538,-189.851]
Z = [958,942,950,945,940,955]

That's the points I was able to catch from my moving ball. Now I would like to be able to compute something like an interpolation or least square with those points to know the trajectory of the ball. I can then know where the ball is going and where it will hit the wall.

I'm not sure of which mathematical tool to use and how to translate it in C++. I've seen lots of resources for 2D interpolation (cubic,...) or least squares, but it seems that it's harder for 3D or I missed something maybe.

Best regards

EDIT : the question is marked as too broad by moderators, so I will reduce the scope with the responses I got : if I use 2D polynomial regression with the 3 plans separately (thx [yephick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1482455/yephick)), what can I use in C++ to implement it ?

Comment: I found this [link](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression#C) which works with GNU Scientific Library. You can found GSL for VS2010 [here](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~shb104/c/files/other/UsingGSLwithVisualStudio.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

For what you are interested in there's hardly any difference between 3D and 2D.

All you do is work with planes **independently** (XY plane, XZ plane, and YZ plane). This will reduce the complexity significantly and allow you to "draw" much simpler diagrams on a piece of paper when you work on this problem.

Once you figured the coordinates in each of the planes it is quite trivial to not only reconcile the coordinates into a 3D space but also provides an added benefit of error checking. For example an X coordinate found in XY plane should match (or be "close enough") to the same X coordinate found in XZ plane.

If the accuracy is not too critical you don't even need to go higher than the first power of polynomial approximation, using just a simple plain-old arithmetical average of the two consequential points.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [spline interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation) to create a smooth trajectory.

If not in the "mood" to implement it yourself, a quick google search will give you open source libraries like SINTEF's [SISL](http://www.sintef.no/Projectweb/Geometry-Toolkits/SISL/) that have such functionallity.